# Populating a QTableWidget in a PyQt5 GUI with a result returned from a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I have made a GUI in PyQt5 that allows you to deal with a database. There is an insert button which allows you to insert data into a database and then using a stored procedure whose parameter is a MySQL query in string format, it passes a select query to the stored procedure whose where clause consists of values just entered.

`

```
    def insert(self):
        try:
            self.table.setRowCount(0)
            QEmpID = self.lineEmpID.text() + "%"
            QFName = self.lineFName.text() + "%"
            QLName = self.lineLName .text() + "%"
            QSalary = self.lineSalary.text() + "%"
            QTask = self.lineTask.text() + "%"
            mydb = mc.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="",database="Office")
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            selectQuery = "SELECT * From Employee WHERE EmpID like '{}' and FirstName like '{}' and LastName like '{}' and Salary like '{}' and Task like '{}'".format(QEmpID, QFName,QLName,QSalary,QTask)
            QEmpID = self.lineEmpID.text() 
            QFName = self.lineFName.text() 
            QLName = self.lineLName.text() 
            QSalary = self.lineSalary.text() 
            QTask = self.lineTask.text() 
            insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Employee Values({},'{}','{}',{},'{}')".format(QEmpID,QFName, QLName, QSalary, QTask)
            mycursor.execute(insertQuery)
            mydb.commit()
            insertResult = mycursor.fetchall()
            mycursor.callProc('fetchData',[selectQuery])

            for result in mycursor.stored_results():
                selectResult = result.fetchall()

            for row_number,row_data in enumerate(selectResult):
                self.table.insertRow(row_number)
                for column_number,data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.table.setItem(row_number,column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    

        except mc.Error as e:
            print(e)
```

The above is my python code for the insert function which is then connected to the insert button.

`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fetchData`(in query1 varchar(1000))
begin
    set @q = query1;
    PREPARE stmt from @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The above is my stored procedure which executes a query passed to it in string format.

However, when I type in the record to be inserted into the fields and then press Insert, the following shows up without any tracebacks or error reports in the IDLE Shell:

[image: Error Image]

The thing is, the record does get inserted into the database and I think the issue is with the calling of stored procedure with a select query passed to it and whose result can then be populated into the QTableWidget.

I can't think of anything right now. Help is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to run your program from the command prompt? Also, you should not create queries with simple string format, but properly use `cursor.execute(<query with placeholders>, <values>)`.

Comment: @musicamante Will running from cmd make any difference? Also thanks for the advice regarding the query

Comment: @musicamante dude, you're a goat
The error was basically that the "p" in callProc was supposed to be lower case and this error only showed in cmd terminal and not in IDLE for some reason

Comment: Good. Remember that IDEs are not always able to show the full traceback of an issue, that's why it's always important to test the code in "normal" conditions outside the "development environment" (so, using a terminal or prompt), *even when the program works*. Note that typos are considered off topic on StackOverflow, so your post will be closed sooner or later. I suggest you to delete it on your own.